# Apache spark: setting spark.eventLog.enabled and spark.eventLog.dir at submit or Spark start

Tags: apache-spark

I would like to set `spark.eventLog.enabled` and `spark.eventLog.dir` at the `spark-submit` or `start-all` level -- not require it to be enabled in the scala/java/python code.
I have tried various things with no success:

#### Setting `spark-defaults.conf` as

```
spark.eventLog.enabled           true
spark.eventLog.dir               hdfs://namenode:8021/directory
```

or

```
spark.eventLog.enabled           true
spark.eventLog.dir               file:///some/where
```

#### Running `spark-submit` as:

```
spark-submit --conf "spark.eventLog.enabled=true" --conf "spark.eventLog.dir=file:///tmp/test" --master spark://server:7077 examples/src/main/python/pi.py
```

#### Starting spark with environment variables:

```
SPARK_DAEMON_JAVA_OPTS="-Dspark.eventLog.enabled=true -Dspark.history.fs.logDirectory=$sparkHistoryDir -Dspark.history.provider=org.apache.spark.deploy.history.FsHistoryProvider -Dspark.history.fs.cleaner.enabled=true -Dspark.history.fs.cleaner.interval=2d"
```

and just for overkill:

```
SPARK_HISTORY_OPTS="-Dspark.eventLog.enabled=true -Dspark.history.fs.logDirectory=$sparkHistoryDir -Dspark.history.provider=org.apache.spark.deploy.history.FsHistoryProvider -Dspark.history.fs.cleaner.enabled=true -Dspark.history.fs.cleaner.interval=2d"
```

Where and how must these things be set to get history on arbitrary jobs?

Answer (score 12):

I solved the problem, yet strangely I had tried this before...
All the same, now it seems like a stable solution:

Create a directory in `HDFS` for logging, say `/eventLogging`

```
hdfs dfs -mkdir /eventLogging
```

Then `spark-shell` or `spark-submit` (or whatever) can be run with the following options:

```
--conf spark.eventLog.enabled=true --conf spark.eventLog.dir=hdfs://<hdfsNameNodeAddress>:8020/eventLogging
```

such as:

```
spark-shell --conf spark.eventLog.enabled=true --conf spark.eventLog.dir=hdfs://<hdfsNameNodeAddress>:8020/eventLogging
```

Comment: Did you ever get it to work with the local filesystem?

Comment: I tried the same method with local filesystem and it works

Comment: @TuanDo can you give specific format how you provided local filesystem

Comment: try --conf spark.eventLog.dir=file:///<local_dir>/

Comment: What is the value of hdfsNameNodeAddress? How do we get this value?

Answer (score 1):

Create a local directory:

```
$ mkdir /tmp/spark-events
```

Run Spark-shell with *--conf spark.eventLog.enabled*

```
$ spark-shell --conf spark.eventLog.enabled --class com.MainClass --packages packages_if_any --master local[4] app.jar
```

Comment: /usr/lib/spark/bin/spark-shell --conf spark.eventLog.enabled=true --conf spark.eventLog.dir=/eventLogging --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi --master yarn --jars /usr/lib/spark/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.11-2.4.0.jar