# Unable to see Spark UI when I submit in yarn-cluster of Hadoop-2.6

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2, spark-graphx

I'm using Apache Spark 1.6 with Cluster of 8 nodes remotely. I'm submitting job using spark-submit like below on master node:

```
hastimal@hadoop-8:/usr/local/spark$ ./bin/spark-submit --class  umkc.graph.SparkRdfCcCount  --master yarn-cluster  --num-executors 7 --executor-memory 52g --executor-cores 7 --driver-memory 52g --conf spark.default.parallelism=49 --conf spark.driver.maxResultSize=4g  --conf spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=4608 --conf spark.yarn.driver.memoryOverhead=4608 --conf spark.akka.frameSize=1200 --conf spark.network.timeout=300  --conf spark.io.compression.codec=lz4 --conf spark.rdd.compress=true --conf spark.eventLog.enabled=true --conf spark.eventLog.dir=hdfs://128.110.152.54:9000/SparkHistory --conf spark.broadcast.compress=true --conf spark.shuffle.spill.compress=true --conf spark.shuffle.compress=true --conf spark.shuffle.manager=sort /users/hastimal/SparkProcessing.jar /inputRDF/data-793-805.nt
```

Everything is fine. I'm getting output without any error but when I go to see Spark UI it doesn't show. In my Spark Scala code I have written like this:

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Spark Processing").set("spark.ui.port","4041")
```

After following couple of things including [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31233830/apache-spark-setting-spark-eventlog-enabled-and-spark-eventlog-dir-at-submit-or) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22676593/why-does-hadoop-fs-mkdir-fail-with-permission-denied) I resolved my issues related to permission and writing in HDFS. When I run `spark-submit` and I see logs in Yarn it shows like this:

```
16/04/25 16:34:23 INFO server.AbstractConnector: Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:4041
16/04/25 16:34:23 INFO util.Utils: Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4041.
16/04/25 16:34:23 INFO ui.SparkUI: Started SparkUI at http://128.110.152.131:4041
16/04/25 16:34:23 INFO cluster.YarnClusterScheduler: Created YarnClusterScheduler
16/04/25 16:34:24 INFO util.Utils: Successfully started service 'org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService' on port 41216.
16/04/25 16:34:24 INFO netty.NettyBlockTransferService: Server created on 41216
16/04/25 16:34:24 INFO storage.BlockManagerMaster: Trying to register BlockManager
16/04/25 16:34:24 INFO storage.BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager 128.110.152.131:41216 with 34.4 GB RAM, BlockManagerId(driver, 128.110.152.131, 41216)
16/04/25 16:34:24 INFO storage.BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager
```

Which means Spark UI has been started on `http://128.110.152.131:4041`which is one of the data node again and when I go to that URL it shows refuse error like below:

[image: This is the refuse error I'm getting]

FYI: All used ports and opened in all machines. Please help me. I want to see DAG of my Spark Job. I'm able to see all yarn applications through Yarn UI. I can see Application UI like below using port 8088:
[image: Application UI]. I want to see Spark UI with DAG like we see in Standalone or using IntelliJ IDE.

Answer (score 1):

In yarn mode application master creates the spark UI. While job is running goto resource manager and click on ApplicationMaster, you will see the UI.

Comment: Thanks but I can see that using 8088 port but I'm not talking about this this. I want to see Spark UI where we can see DAG like we can see when we run on local Standalone or in IDE using http://localhost:4040. See I edited to be more clear.

Comment: Application master starts the spark UI. If you click ApplicationMaster link on ResourceManager job page. It will take you to sparkUI.

Comment: Thanks @vgunnu. I did and it shows same as http://128.110.152.131:404. I mean same error as in above picture-1. In either way by using your method or using http://128.110.152.131:4041 it shows same error. Looks like routing to same page but refused to connect.....

Comment: how many interfaces are there on node? Login to the node and use netstat or lsof to see which ports are open on which interface.